# Cell value is wrong - subtract does mistake

Tags: google-sheets

I have a fairly large file with few dozens of sheets in it and in the past month or so, I have identified about 3-4 mistakes, where a simple subtraction (K7=K6-K8) does not equal to the actual number. Even if you click into the cell, the "hellp" count in blue box does say the correct number, but the actual cell not. Fix is quite simple - only to rewrite the actual equation, but it is quite annoying to look for the mistakes. I have made a screen record to demonstrate the problem as I cannot really provide access to the file (sensitive information) - https://www.veed.io/view/9d52b8bf-7bc5-4032-8462-3c2dd7e6024a?panel=share. One of the cells that is being subtracted is connected to a =IMPORTRANGE, but that works fine.

I have recreated the part of the file in here, not sure if it helps
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nfzfVrGalCpyTOXnv-BoUe3gZVJzeBlO20Y85KzQla8/edit?usp=sharing

The problem occurs randomly and once repaired, it does not repeat (technically, going back in time would repeat the issue, but the file has to be operational)

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing a similar problem. It involves a basic subtraction operation, but despite using the correct function, I consistently receive an incorrect result. However, the issue resolves itself upon **reloading** the Google Sheet.